# replace mapped drive k:/ and K:\ with the unc path in all files in drive using python re sub

Tags: python

after iterating over all files in a drive, i want to change all references to the mapped drive with the unc path

Can't figure out why this doesn't work or whether this is the right way to go about it.

```
    with open(file, 'w') as ts:
        for item in c:
           itemchange=re.compile(re.escape('k:/'),re.IGNORECASE)
           itemswitch=itemchange.sub('//covenas/decisionsupport/',item)
           itemchange=re.compile(re.escape('k:\'),re.IGNORECASE)
           itemswitch=itemchange.sub('//covenas/decisionsupport/',itemswitch)
           itemchange=re.compile(re.escape('i:/'),re.IGNORECASE)
           itemswitch=itemchange.sub('//covenas/spssdata/',itemswitch)
           itemchange=re.compile(re.escape('i:\'),re.IGNORECASE)
           itemswitch=itemchange.sub('//covenas/spssdata/',itemswitch)
           ts.write(itemswitch)
```

this section comes after

```
from os import walk

def walkChange(mypath):
    f = []
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(mypath):
        for file in filenames:
            f.append(dirpath+file)
    return f

mypath='k:/meinzer/production/'
f=walkChange(mypath)

list=[]
[list.append(i) for i in f if i.upper().endswith('SPS')]
#[i for i in list]
#testing with a file
#file='K:/meinzer/production/ps/development code/testd.sps'
for file in list:
    with open(file, "r") as f: 
        c=f.readlines()  
    with open(file, 'w') as ts:
        for item in c:
           itemchange=re.compile(re.escape('k:/'),re.IGNORECASE)
           itemswitch=itemchange.sub('//covenas/decisionsupport/',item)
           itemchange=re.compile(re.escape('k:\'),re.IGNORECASE)
           itemswitch=itemchange.sub('//covenas/decisionsupport/',itemswitch)
           itemchange=re.compile(re.escape('i:/'),re.IGNORECASE)
           itemswitch=itemchange.sub('//covenas/spssdata/',itemswitch)
           itemchange=re.compile(re.escape('i:\'),re.IGNORECASE)
           itemswitch=itemchange.sub('//covenas/spssdata/',itemswitch)
           ts.write(itemswitch)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lines:

```
itemchange=re.compile(re.escape('k:\'),re.IGNORECASE)
```

(and `re.escape('i:\')`) need to have their backslashes doubled. I'm shocked that's not giving you a nasty SyntaxError

Comment: omg, that's so simple.  my brain crashed... one of those days!  thank you.